# google cloud engine android backend. Unrecognized element <servlet> error?

Tags: android, xml, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-endpoints

I've just made a basic model for the back-end of an android app using the 'add google cloud module' feature. I've created an endpoint and every time I try to run or build the project I get this error. The error before this was that it could not locate app engine-web at all which I fixed as the file name was web instead, so I changed it to app engine-web. after that it hit me with the "Unrecognized element "? full error log below.

```
Feb 29, 2016 9:13:40 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Feb 29, 2016 9:13:41 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
SEVERE: Received exception processing C:\Users\ahmed\AndroidStudioProjects\HouseSplittr\Backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Unrecognized element <servlet>
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processSecondLevelNode(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:181)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:65)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:132)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:76)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:170)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:414)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:159)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:265)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid configuration
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.reportDeferredConfigurationException(DevAppServerImpl.java:474)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid appengine-web.xml(C:\Users\ahmed\AndroidStudioProjects\HouseSplittr\Backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml) - Unrecognized element <servlet>
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:172)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:414)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:159)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:265)
    ... 8 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please share more information, specially your `web.xml` and `appengine-web.xml` file along side your build file

Comment: Hi i've managed to fix it somehow, cant remember exactly but hey ho! at least im past it.